# whenever the flutter doctor always makes this mistake he says he can't find the file

Tags: flutter, android-sdk-2.3

Output of `flutter doctor`

```sh
C:\WINDOWS\system32>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.18363.778], locale pt-BR)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\egacg\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the SDK (Android SDK version 29.0.3). 
If you are using android studio you can click on `Tools->SDK Manager`, Select the version you need and hit apply/OK.

[image]

Then run **flutter doctor** again.